# Change the domain mautic uses when generating the urls (previews, emails, landing pages)

Tags: mautic

I have a docker instance of mautic and it works like a charm.

The only issue is that

- the urls generated inside emails (eg. Unsubscribe URL)
- the preview links of the forms/emails
- the landing page urls

are all pointing to the wrong domain name (network IP address of the guest machine)

I'd like to change that to the url of my mautic installation.

I've checked out the settings with no luck and also looked at all the files inside `app/config` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Can't be sure about doing inside docker, but in the past we have been using reverse proxy and pointing it to the docker instance, also this helped us using more than one instance along with setting up ssl certificate as well. here's one setup example:

https://github.com/stollz/MauticSSLDocker

hope this helps.